Linear models to compare SNP categories between patients
I have 8 patients (GROUP: 3 healthy, 5 disease). For each patient, I determined single nucleotide polymorphisms (SNPs) and annotated the effect of the SNPs (EFFECT_CATEGORY). Each SNP (~3000 per patient) can have multiple effects which are categories like "missense" or "synonymous". In total there are 20 categories so that I can construct a count table of 20 categories x 8 patients. In addition, the number of SNPs detected in a patient and hence the category count is dependent on the sequencing depth (SEQ_DEPTH) per patient.
For each category I want to test if there is a significant difference between the groups (healthy vs disease). I started with a Chi-Square test on the summed counts per group and got interesting results. But I think the test might be too simple and does not take into account the sequencing depth or patient effects.
So I thought a generalized linear mixed model is suited. Using the R lme4 negative binomial (NB) model, I can model the effect counts N as follows:
glmer.nb(N ~ GROUP * EFFECT_CATEGORY + offset(log(SEQ_DEPTH)) + (1 | PATIENT_ID), data=data)

I used the NB because most biological count data do not follow Poisson mean/variance relationship.
Is the overall approach correct?

Welcome to Cross Validated! This might be too small a study to get useful answers. Could you please edit the question to say how many SNPs you are evaluating? Please provide extra information by editing the question directly, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Many thanks @EdM! Per patient I have about 3000 SNPs. I am aware that the patient number is generally to little for SNP comparison and the analysis is only explorative. However, I thought having few patients would reduce the power of the test. Hence, the differences would not be significant?

Take a simple example with your sample size: a binary marker that is positive for all 3 "healthy" and negative for all 5 "disease," perfect alignment with GROUP membership. A Fisher exact test gives a p-value of 0.018. That's essentially the best you can do for any single comparison with a sample like this.
You then have a big problem with multiple comparisons. The more null hypotheses that you test, the more likely that some will appear "significant" just by chance. In genomics studies, this is typically handled by control of the "false discovery rate" (FDR), the proportion of "significant" hypotheses that are likely to be false.
The Benjamini-Hochberg method controls FDR as follows. Choose an FDR level of $\alpha$, for tests of $m$ hypotheses that are labeled as $H_i$ with corresponding (uncorrected) p-values $P_i$. Quoting from Wikipedia, after sorting so that the $P_i$ are in increasing order:

For a given $\alpha$, find the largest $k$ such that $P_k \leq \frac{k}{m} \alpha$

Reject the null hypothesis (i.e., declare discoveries) for all $H_i$ for $i = 1, \ldots, k$


You plan to evaluate $m=3000$ markers. The lowest $P_i$ you can get for any of them is 0.018. Say that you are willing to accept an FDR ($\alpha$) of 0.2. You would then need at least 270 of the markers to have this perfect marker alignment between healthy and disease to declare any of them "significant," and of those about 20% will still be false positives.
Your situation, with multiple marker categories, will be even more difficult. You certainly are welcome to explore, but you run a big risk of chasing down "positive" associations that just occurred by chance.
A few thoughts specific to the model you propose, although I'm not an expert on SNP analysis.
First, it's not clear that the probability of finding a SNP is as simple a function of sequencing depth as your model posits with its offset.
Second, linkage disequilibrium in human populations can mean that SNPs aren't independently distributed within individuals. That further complicates the analysis.
Third, although random effects like those you propose are used in large-scale sudies, 8 individuals is close to the lower limit. See this page for discussion.
I'd suggest that, instead of starting out completely on your own, you should take advantage of the large volume of work already done on SNP analyses. The Bioconductor Project has many well vetted tools. This Tutorial in Biostatistics, Statistics in Medicine 34: 3769-3792 (2015) by Reed et al. might be a good place to start.
In response to comments
From comments, it's now clear that the interest is in differences in prevalence of categories of SNPs rather than SNPs per se. That greatly diminishes the multiple comparisons problem, but does require some care.
There are two big problems here. One is that there is a fixed cutoff for calling a SNP from the RNAseq data: it will be called if there are at least 10 reads at the locus, but not called otherwise. The other is that there might be substantial lack of independence: a single SNP might be annotated in more than one category, so categorizations aren't independent; the SNP calling depends on the level of gene expression, which might differ between "healthy" and "disease" cases and thus might differentially affect the ability to detect SNPs.
I'd recommend using a binomial model here. A negative binomial can be appropriate for evaluating gene expression quantitatively, but that's not what you evidently care about. For each individual you know the number of SNPs that were called, based on whether the threshold was passed. That's how the sequencing depth comes into play: not continuously as an offset, but in determining the total number of SNPs observed in an individual. Then, for an individual, you would evaluate the proportion of that number of SNPs in each category. A single SNP either is or isn't in any single category. That's a binary outcome, calling for a binomial regression (e.g., logistic regression).
Then you might start with the structure you propose but use binomial regression with appropriately formatted data. For example, in R you could specify the outcome as the proportion of SNPs an individual had in a category, with a weights argument specifying the total number of SNPs found for the individual. That accomplishes the type of thing you wanted to do with the offset, but in a way that better matches your data.
I don't have a good way to deal with the potential lack of independence in categorizing SNPs or the problems introduced by depending on sc-RNAseq instead of genomic sequencing to detect SNPs. I think you'll just have to acknowledge those as limitations to your analysis. You presumably will examine how gene expression also differs between "healthy" and "disease" and how that might be affecting which and how many SNPs you can detect.

Hello @EdM, Many thanks for your input! My apologies if I did not state the problem clearly. I do not test m=3000 SNPs but m=20 effect categories that summarize the SNPs. Hence, the 3000 SNP counts are distributed over 20 categories that I want to compare between groups. I do BH correction on the resulting p-values.
I very much agree with all of your points about SNP analysis and many thanks for the link about random effects! That is exactly the kind of input I am looking for.

One comment about the sequencing depth. I am working with 5' prime single cell RNA-seq data. For SNP detection the reads are pilled up and compared to a reference SNP data base. For SNP calling a minimum of 10 reads must cover a given SNP position. That is why I used the sequencing depth as offset and did not trust the results of the Chi-squared test.

@BackFish now that I understand the setup better, I think that there might be a problem with the independence assumptions underlying your model, as a single SNP can be assigned to multiple categories. Also, I'm not sure that the log-offset for sequencing depth captures the actual data-generation process, as there's a hard cutoff at 10 reads. Finally, basing this on sc-RNAseq might pose a problem as differences in mRNA expression levels between groups could mean differences in the ability to detect a SNP. I'll try to come back to this later in the week.

@BackFish I added a bit to the answer to address your clarification of the situation.

thank you very much, that was incredible helpful!
